# Find 3rd point in a line using c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I am working in c++ application. And its new to me. Here I write a function which gain two coordinates of a line. I have to process these coordinates and find another point which in that same line. 
I will gain `A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2)` coordinates. 
need to find
`C(x3,y3)` coordinates.
Therefore I calculate the Slope of given line.

`Double slope = (x1-x2)/(y1-y2);`

And I know the distance of 3rd point from A point.

`Double dis = sqrt(pow(x2-x1) + pow(y2-y1)) * 1.35 ;`

I want to find new coordinates x3 ,y3 using `Slope` and `dis`.

Can anyone help me to solve this please.

To calculate the x3 I can use mathematical part,

`x3 = slope * y3 -------------------1`

`dis = sqrt(pow(x3-x1) + pow(y3-y1)) ------------2`

using these 2 equations which generating in run time , I want to calculate `x3` and `y3`.

Comment: Slope of the line isn't `(x1-x2)/(y1-y2)` but `(y1-y2)/(x1-x2)`

Comment: don't you need to specify _which_ power to raise to in the `pow` function?

Answer (score 6):

Too much math.

```
x3 = (x1 - x2) * 1.35 + x2
y3 = (y1 - y2) * 1.35 + y2
```

Comment: This solves the specific problem because the distance needed is proportional to the distance between the two points. IMO is however a bit too specific (and against the idea that a good answer should be long and explaining).

Comment: @6502: some of the great answers are incredibly short... just sufficient to provoke the "aha!" "eureka" "yappari" moment - consider zen/chan buddhism... ;-P

Comment: @Tony: I agree. But IMO this is not one of those cases.

Comment: @6502: Well, I upvoted your answer and not this one, so I guess I must too, though I think I'll upvote this one now. It's been the lack of semicolons above that deeply bothers me ;-).

Comment: @Tony: I upvoted this answer too, none the less I think slides a bit a bit down the too-concise and too-specific side. By the way I've some missing semicolons also in my answer :-) ... my idea was actually to use latex notation for those two lines, but probably it would have been less readable for who is not using latex (and on the other side who uses latex probably already knows why parametric equations are better for 2d problems).

Answer (score 5):

Unless you are working with a "1.5d" graph `y=y(x)` you should never use formulas based on `y=m*x+q` because that doesn't work for vertical lines (and works poorly for near-vertical lines).

In your case the best approach is to use the parametric equation for a line

```
x = x1 + t * dx
y = y1 + t * dy
```

where `dx = x2 - x1` and `dy = y2 - y1` are proportional to the components of the direction unit vector oriented from P1 to P2 and are used instead of `m` and `q` to define the line (avoiding any problem with vertical or almost vertical lines).

If you need a point on a specific distance then you just need to find the actual unit vector components with

```
double dx = x2 - x1;
double dy = y2 - y1;
double dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
dx /= dist;
dy /= dist;
```

and then the coordinates of the point you need are

```
double x3 = x1 + prescribed_distance * dx;
double y3 = y1 + prescribed_distance * dy;
```

or using `-prescribed_distance` instead depending on which side you want the point: toward P2 or away from it?

If however the prescribed distance is proportional to the current distance between the two points the normalization is not needed and the result can be the simpler:

```
double x3 = x1 + (x2 - x1) * k;
double y3 = y1 + (y2 - y1) * k;
```

where `k` is the ratio between the prescribed distance and the distance between the two points (once again with positive or negative sign depending on which side you are interested in).

By using parametric equations `x=x(t), y=y(t)` instead of explicit equations `y=y(x)` in addition to not having artificial singularity problems that depend on the coordinate system you also get formulas that are trivial to extend in higher dimensions. For example for a 3d line you just basically need to add `z` coordinate to the above formulas in the very same way `x` and `y` are used...

Comment: This is totally unmerited but for some reason "works bad" set off my inner grammar `$DANGEROUSLY_RADICAL_POLITICAL_PARTY`. The correct way to word it is, of course, "works poorly."

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Thanks for the correction. I'm italian and my english sucks poorly ;-)

Comment: I actually couldn't tell. I thought it was just a brainfart. So apparently it doesn't suck as much as you think it does.

Comment: Is there a typo in this line, double y3 = y3 + prescribed_distance * dy; Is it y3 or something else?

Comment: @SyaifulNizamYahya: it was a typo; fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute the first equation `"y3 = slope * x3"` into the 2nd equation `"dis = sqrt(pow(x3-x1) + pow(y3-y1))"`, and square both sides, you get a quadratic which you can solve using the quadratic formula.

After substitution you get:

```
dis^2 = (x3-x1)^2 + (slope*x3 - y1)^2
```

Square both sides:

```
(slope^2+1)*x3^2 + (-2*slope*y1-2*x1) + 2*y1^2 = dis^2
```

Solve for x3 using the quadratic formula:

```
x3 = (2*slope*y1+2*x1) +/- sqrt((2*slope*y1+2*x1)^b - 4*(slope^2+1)*(2*y1^2-dis^2))/(2*(slope^2+1))
```

Substitute x3 into the first equation to get y3:

```
y3 = slope * x3
```

Comment: For this problem (as quite often happens) using `y = m * x + q` is the wrong approach. Parametric equation is a better fit...