# Implementation of feature detection algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, line, implementation, ransac

I'm fairly new to programming and would like to know how to start implementing the following algorithm in C++,

Given a binary image where pixels with intensity 255 show **edges** and pixels with intensity 0 show **the background**, find line segments longer than `n` pixels in the image. `t` is a counter showing the number of iterations without finding a line, and `tm` is the maximum number of iterations allowed before exiting the program.

1. Let `t=0`.
2. Take two edge points randomly from the image and find equation of the line passing
   through them.
3. Find `m`, the number of other edge points in the image that are within distance d pixels of
   the line.
4. If `m > n`, go to Step 5.

   Otherwise (`m ≤ n`), increment `t` by 1 and if `t < tm` go to Step 2, and
   if `t ≥ tm` exit program.
5. Draw the line and remove the edge points falling within distance `d` pixels of it from the
   image. Then, go to Step 1

Basically, I just want to randomly pick two points from the image, find the distance between them, and if that distance is too small, I would detect a line between them.

I would appreciate if a small code snippet is provided, to get me started.
this is more like a RANSAC parametric line detection. I would also keep this post updated if I get it done.

```
/* Display Routine */

#include "define.h"

ByteImage bimg;                     //A copy of the image to be viewed
int width, height;                  //Window dimensions
GLfloat zoomx = 1.0, zoomy = 1.0;   //Pixel zoom
int win;                            //Window index

void resetViewer();

void reshape(int w, int h) {
glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
if ((w!=width) || (h!=height)) {
    zoomx=(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)bimg.nc;
    zoomy=(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)bimg.nr;
    glPixelZoom(zoomx,zoomy);
}
width=w; height=h;

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0.0, (GLdouble)w, 0.0, (GLdouble)h);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
glutPostRedisplay();
if((button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) && (state == GLUT_DOWN) &&
    (zoomx==1.0) && (zoomy==1.0)){
printf(" row=%d, col=%d, int=%d.\n", y,x, (int)bimg.image[(bimg.nr-1-y)*bimg.nc+x]);
        glutPostRedisplay();
}
}

void display() {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glRasterPos2i(0, 0);         
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

glDrawPixels((GLsizei)bimg.nc,(GLsizei)bimg.nr,   GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bimg.image);
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Check OpenCV examples and functions. The [HoughLines function](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) may be something you can use. OpenCV also present functions to detect edge, [features](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html) and others things.

Comment: i know houghlines, and houghlinesP detect lines but i want to try to Implement the above algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume you have an `int[XDIMENSION][YDIMENSION]`

> Let t=0.

```
int t = 0; // ;-)
```

> Take two edge points randomly from the image and find equation of the line passing through them.

Brute force: you could randomly search the image for points and re-search when they are not edge points

```
struct Point {
  int x;
  int y;
};

bool is_edge(Point a) {
  return image[a.x][a.y] == 255;
}

int randomUpto(int upto) {
  int r = rand() % upto;
  return r;
}
```

, which needs the pseudo-random number generator to be initialized via

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

To find edge points

```
  Point a;
  do {
    a.x = randomUpto(XDIMENSION);
    a.y = randomUpto(YDIMENSION);
  } while ( ! is_edge(a) );
```

> Find `m`, the number of other edge points in the image that are within distance `d` pixels of the line.

You need the line between the points. Some searching yields [this fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620943/1587329), which leads to

```
std::vector<Point> getLineBetween(Point a, Point b) {
  double dx = b.x - a.x;
  double dy = b.y - a.y;
  double dist = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  dx /= dist;
  dy /= dist;
  std::vector<Point> points;
  points.push_back(a);
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < 2*dist; i++ ) {
    Point tmp;
    tmp.x = a.x + (int)(i * dx /2.0);
    tmp.y = a.y + (int)(i * dy /2.0);
    if ( tmp.x != points.back().x
     || tmp.y != points.back().y ) {
      points.push_back(tmp);
    }
  }
  return points;
}
```

Do you see a pattern here? Isolate the steps into substeps, ask google, look at [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/), try out stuff until it works.

Your next steps might be to

- create a [distance function](https://www.google.de/search?q=distance%20function), euclidean should suffice
- find all points next to line (or next to a point, which is easier) based on the distance function

Try out some and come back if you still need help.

Comment: i need to do this after i load an image file right?

Comment: right now i can load and display an image, but how do i detect lines in that image?, given below is the code, i just need to know what should be done in "case 3: "